# Creating an RSS reader in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

Using the Feedjira gem, how would one go about parsing feeds in an app where users can log in and set up their own feeds, then display those feeds in a view. My current understanding is to use a 'Feed' and 'Entry' model/controller however with the additional 'User' model/controller this enters three nested resources territory which I have discovered requires polymorphic associations? I've found a few sources on using the Feedjira gem but none have given me a concrete understanding of how to use it. For example creating a model like

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.update_from_feed(feed_name)
    feed = Feed.find_by_name(feed_name)
    feed_data = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed.feed_url)
    add_entries(feed_data.entries, feed)
  end

  private
  def self.add_entries(entries, feed)
    entries.each do |entry|
      break if exists? :entry_id => entry.id

        create!(
            :entry_id     => entry.id,
            :feed_id      => feed.id,
            :url          => entry.url,
            :title        => entry.title.sanitize,
            :summary      => entry.summary.sanitize,
            :description  => entry.content.sanitize,
            :published_at => entry.published
        )

      end
    end
  end
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447810/matt)

But I'm unclear in how this would interface with a feed controller and ultimately display a feed, or even just be able to access @entry.something on the view so I can work with it from there. I apologize if this question is too vague, let me know if I'm incorrect in the polymorphic associations assumption and if there is an easy implementation of the routing. Maybe a link to some documentation that could give me a better understanding of my current situation.

Comment: This is something like: User has_many feeds...How does Entry relate to this? Can you please elaborate how the three model relate....

Comment: It would be User has_many feeds. Feed has_many entries, belongs_to User. Entry belongs_to Feed.

Comment: May be you can try something like this: User model:
has_many :feeds
has_many :entries, through: :feeds

Feed model:
has_many :entries
belongs_to :user
Entry model:
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :feed.......Then you can find feed and feed.entries.each can give you the entry for  each feed....Let me know if you were trying to do something like this